# Background parent container smaller with image partially outside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I’m working on a custom template and I have to create a block like this :

Desktop :

[image]

Mobile

[image]

I have difficulties  in obtaining this result : the background color of the parent container is smaller and the image is partially outside.

For now, I have managed to do this but I don’t think it is good because I have to set some max-height in pixels and position absolute on the image.

```css
#block-devis-home {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 450px;
  background: #0e182c;
}

#block-devis-home img {
  position: absolute;
  left: -200px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.block-devis-home-text {
  padding: 0 30px;
}

#block-devis-home h2,
#block-devis-home p {
  color: #fff;
}

#block-devis-home h2 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 56px 0 36px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">

  <section class="block-home">

    <div class="row">

      <div id="block-devis-home">

        <div class="col-md-6">

          <img class="img-full-width" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50">

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

          <div class="block-devis-home-text">

            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sapien etiam, nunc amet dolor ac odio mauris justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sapien etiam, nunc amet dolor ac odio mauris justo.</p>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

Is there an other way I could explore ?

Comment: on large screen, you don't want the image to overlap on the right block?

Comment: What layout do you want for smaller screens?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh yes the image is aligned right to 1st column.

Comment: Ok, so the image you showed on the top is what you want to achieve is ***just*** for small screen, right?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh The image is desktop screen. On mobile, the result is different.

Comment: @sol on smaller screen, the image is on top.

Comment: @sol I've updated my question with a mobile wireframe.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh I've updated my question with a mobile wireframe.

Comment: @SébastienGicquel, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired output by just using `border:white` on your background of parent element.

```css
.image {
  /*   position:absolute; */
  /* right:0; */
}

.image>img {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  left: -10vw;
}

.rightbox {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.parent {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: red;
  /*   border-left:100px solid white; */
  /*   margin:0px 30px; */
  border-left: 15vw solid white;
  border-right: 2vw solid white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
}

.widthAdjust {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.block-devis-home-text {
  height: 240px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .parent {
    border: 0;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  .image {
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 20px solid white;
    border-right: 20px solid white;
  }
  .image>img {
    /*     position: absolute; */
    top: -50px;
    /*     border:1px solid blue; */
    left: 0;
  }
  .block-devis-home-text {
    height: max-content;
  }
  .rightbox {
    border-left: 20px solid white;
    border-right: 20px solid white;
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="block-home parent">

  <div class="container widthAdjust">
    <div class="row flex">
      <div class="col-md-6 image">

        <img class="img-full-width" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50">

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 rightbox">

        <div class="block-devis-home-text">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sapien etiam, nunc amet dolor ac odio mauris justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sapien etiam, nunc amet dolor ac odio mauris justo.</p>
          </div>

        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for the work. I think the result has to be different. The image is not outside. It is the parent container which is smaller.

Comment: image has the property `absolute` and having `z-index` of 3, so it can be placed anywhere, all you need to adjust is it's positioning.

Comment: I understand. But if you use position absolute, the image moves to the left. On the wireframe, the image is align right to 1st colum. It is partially outside because the parent container (with red back ground) is smaller.

Comment: Ohhk, I assumed the parent is `skyblue` section in my example, but as you're saying, it's the red block, which is the `parent`, and the image is supposed to be outside of that red block i.e `parent`. correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can try this.
    css:
     body,html{
     height:100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     }

.float-left{
float:left;
}
.block-home{
float:none !important;
margin:auto;
height:250px;
background-color:red;
position:relative;

}
.col-md-6.text-center{
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
.text-center h2{
  font-size:26px;
}
.image-class{
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 75%;
    background: #afb8bf;
    font-family: monospace;
    background-position: center center;
    left: -8%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-image: url(https://top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/7-small-flowers.jpg);
    background-size: cover;

}
 @media only screen and (max-width : 760px) and (min-width : 480px) {
.image-class {
     top: 0;
    height: 50%;
    background: #afb8bf;
    font-family: monospace;
    background-position: center center;
    left: 24%;
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(-25%);
    background-image: url(https://top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/7-small-flowers.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
.col-md-6.text-center {
    height: 50%;

}
    }
HTML:


<div class="container-fluid">

  <section class="block-home col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
   <div class="image-class col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">

  </div>

   <section class="text-center col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sapien etiam, nunc amet dolor ac odio
            mauris justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sapien etiam, nunc amet dolor ac odio mauris justo.</p>

   </section>

  </section>

</div>
    And import bootstrap cdn.
```

Comment: Thank you for the work. I think the result has to be different. The image is not outside. It is the parent container which is smaller.